# How to call action of another contract within a contract?

Tags: smart-contract, action, permissions

If I'm right then to call the event of another contract, I need to configure the permissions (allow the call).
For example, I have contract aliceclass:

```
class aliceclass : public contract
{
  public:
    aliceclass(account_name self) : contract(self){}

    /// @abi action
    void callbobact(){
       //call the Nikita contract method 
       ...
    }
};
EOSIO_ABI(aliceclass, (callbobact))
```

I have contract bobclass:

```
class bobclass : public contract
{
  public:
    bobclass(account_name self) : contract(self){}

    /// @abi action
    void bobact(){
        print("Hello world!"); 
    }
};
EOSIO_ABI(bobclass, (bobact))
```

I create two accounts `alice` and `bob`, deploy `aliceclass` with `alice` account and `bobclass` with `bob` account. When I try to implement `callbobact` like this:

```
action(
    permission_level{_self , N(active)},
    N(bob),              
    N(bobact),
    std::make_tuple()
).send();
```

When I call action `callbobact` authentication error occurs. 
How to configure permissions for `bob` and `alice`? Do I need to use a multisig for this?

Comment: also sometimes there are problems with functions with no parameters. i would add a param to `bobact()` and therefore an argument to `std::make_tuple()` too

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is as follows:

**1.** I create a new account:

```
$ cleos create account eosio caller PUB_KEY PUB_KEY
```

**2.**  I extend `alice@eosio.code` permissions under `caller@active`:

```
$ cleos set account permission caller active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<PUB_KEY>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"alice","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p caller
```

**3.** I modify the `eosio::permission_level{_self , N(active)}` initialisation to `eosio::permission_level{account, N(active)}`

**4.** I modify `callbobact()` to`callbobact( account_name account )`

**5.** I call `callbobact()` with the following:

```
$ cleos push action alice callbobact '["caller"]' -p caller
```

**6.** I pray it works

Comment: cleos set account permission caller active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<PUB_KEY>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"alice","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p caller
------>
`ERROR: ExtrasError: [[{"key": "<PUB_KEY>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"alice","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]} owner]
set parameters dealing with account permissions`

Comment: yeah you'd need to replace PUB_KEY with the actual public key

Comment: I did it(I just hide it)

Comment: it sounds like a typo somewhere in the command. you shouldn't enclose your PUB_KEY between angle brackets if you're doing this (i.e. PUB_KEY not <PUB_KEY>)

Comment: command seems to work for me. do you have an account `alice`? this is the command i run on my testnet running EOSIO 1.1 `cleos set account permission caller active {"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"alice","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]} owner -p caller`

Answer (score 0):

Update, according to [the latest docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/sending-an-inline-transaction-to-external-contract)

---

In the class with the action to be called, add a public action_wrapper, so for the OPs example:

`using bob_action = action_wrapper<"bobact"_n, &bobclass::bobact>;`

Then, construct and call this action wrapper in the caller class:

```
bobclass::bob_action _bobact{"bobclass"_n, {get_self(), "active"_n}};
_bobact.send();
```

In the above code, we created an instance of the action wrapper from bobclass. The first parameter in construction is the name of the contract, the second parameter is the permission being used to call the external action. The first parameter of the permission object is the caller contract name (get_self()), and the second parameter is the name of the permission.

Calling ".send()" on an action wrapper will call the action, and if there are any parameters to the action, you would include them here (".send(param1, param2, etc.);").